# CSS Element Fixed Position On Page

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have some html and some css like this:

```
.profile-sidebar {
  background-color: #666666;
  height: 100%;
  width: 14%;
}

.profile-title {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 250%;
}

body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.profile-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  height: 15%;
}

.profile-accounts-bar {
  background-color: #f84646;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -20%;
  padding-left: 20%;
}


<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="profile-sidebar"> </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="profile-title">[NAME] Social Media Accounts</h1>
    <div class="everything">
      <div class="profile-accounts-bar">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="profile-footer">

  </div>
```

but so far, it looks like this: https://haxified.is-a-me.me/34f6b82f.png
and I want it to look like this:
https://haxified.is-a-me.me/a3545a93.png - That is illustrator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: You have written css but how we find which element is `.profile-sidebar` or `.profile-title` .... ??

Answer (score 0):

Using fixed elements all the places to align the layout is a bad technique. You can simply use the `float` elements to align your layouts like below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="profile-sidebar"></div>
  <div class="main">
      <div class="profile-title">[NAME] Social Media Accounts</div>
      <div class="everything">
          <div class="profile-accounts-bar"> </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 <div class="profile-footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 html, body {height:100%;}
 .profile-sidebar {
    background-color: #666666;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14%;
    float:left;
  }

  .profile-title {  
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-size: 250%;
  }

  body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }

  .profile-footer {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0%;
     width: 100%;
     left:14.5%;
     background-color: #4D4D4D;
     height: 15%;
  }

  .profile-accounts-bar {
    background-color: #f84646;
    height: 100%;
    width: 5%;  
  }
  .main {float:left; width:86%; height:100%}
  .everything {height:100%}
```

```css
html, body {height:100%;}
.profile-sidebar {
  background-color: #666666;
  height: 100%;
  width: 14%;
  float:left;
}

.profile-title {  
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 250%;
}

body {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.profile-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  left:14.5%;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  height: 15%;
}

.profile-accounts-bar {
  background-color: #f84646;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;  
}
.main {float:left; width:86%; height:100%}
.everything {height:100%}

**Code Snippet**
```

```html
<div class="profile-sidebar"> </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="profile-title">[NAME] Social Media Accounts</div>
    <div class="everything">
      <div class="profile-accounts-bar">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="profile-footer">

  </div>
```

My simple suggestion is go with Bootstrap for these kind of layouts. They have lot of options and support for responsible layout also.